# In Python, can a dict with currentThread() as key cause memory leaks?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, memory-leaks

I'm debugging memory leaks in a Django application, and could something curious in `django_cachepurge`:

```
from threading import currentThread

_urls_to_purge = {}

def add_purge_url(url):
    # ....

    _urls_to_purge.setdefault(currentThread(), set()).add(url)
```

Is such construct prone to memory leaks?
I suspect so, unless I'm not familiar with some Python magic here.
There is no location where the dict is cleaned up.

Comment: Why don't you use `threading.local().urls_to_purge`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `currentThread` returns, but you probably can use the built-in `id` or `hash` functions on it to get a safe value.

If lookup isn't enough, e.g. because you want to iterate over the container, there is `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`.

Comment: I've added the import of `currentThread()`, so you take it into consideration

Comment: In that case your answer is yes. The reference prevents the few bytes of the Thread instance from being collected. I doubt anything serious is left hanging, since cPython threads don't map to machine threads anyway.